# How to connect to a database with visual studio code?

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-code

I want to connect to an existing database with visual studio code, I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try using extensions in VSCode to connect to your database

Write in the search type of your database: PostgreSQL or MySQL, and choose one of extensions

For example, this guide for connection PostgreSQL in VSCode:
https://www.infallibletechie.com/2021/02/how-to-connect-heroku-postgres-from_17.html

---

Or try this manual: https://www.techielass.com/connect-to-a-sql-database-with-visual-studio-code/